# How to compare a word in one list to another word in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list here:

**list1**

```
 ['mississippi', 'well', 'worth', 'reading', 'not', 'commonplace', 'river', 'contrary', 'ways', 'remarkable', 'considering', 'missouri', 'main', 'branch', 'longest', 'river', 'world--four', 'miles', 'seems', 'safe', 'say', 'also', 'crookedest', 'river', 'since', 'in', 'one', 'part', 'journey', 'uses', 'one', 'three', 'miles', 'cover', 'same', 'ground', 'crow', 'fly', 'in', 'six', 'seventy-five', 'it', 'discharges', 'three', 'water', 'st', 'lawrence', 'twenty-five', 'as', 'as', 'rhine', 'three', 'thirty-eight', 'times', 'as', 'much', 'as', 'the', 'thames', 'other', 'river', 'so', 'vast', 'drainage-basin:', 'it', 'draws', 'its', 'water', 'supply', 'twenty-eight', 'states', 'territories', 'delaware', 'the', 'atlantic', 'seaboard', 'the', 'country', 'idaho', 'on', 'the', 'pacific', 'slope--a', 'spread', 'forty-five', 'degrees', 'longitude', 'the', 'mississippi', 'receives', 'carries', 'the', 'gulf', 'water', 'from', 'fifty-four', 'subordinate', 'rivers', 'are', 'navigable', 'steamboats', 'from', 'hundreds', 'that', 'are', 'navigable', 'flats', 'and', 'keels', 'the', 'area', 'its', 'drainage-basin', 'is', 'as', 'as', 'the', 'combined', 'areas', 'england', 'wales', 'scotland', 'ireland', 'france', 'spain', 'portugal', 'germany', 'austria', 'italy', 'and', 'turkey', 'and', 'almost', 'all', 'this', 'wide', 'region', 'is', 'fertile', 'the', 'mississippi', 'valley', 'proper', 'is', 'exceptionally', 'so']
```

I also have another list of common words here:

**list2**

```
['a', 'about', 'after', 'again', 'against', 'ago', 'all', 'along', 'also', 'always', 'an', 'and', 'another', 'any', 'are', 'around', 'as', 'at', 'away', 'back', 'be', 'because', 'been', 'before', 'began', 'being', 'between', 'both', 'but', 'by', 'came', 'can', 'come', 'could', 'course', 'day', 'days', 'did', 'do', 'down', 'each', 'end', 'even', 'ever', 'every', 'first', 'for', 'four', 'from', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'going', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'had', 'half', 'has', 'have', 'he', 'head', 'her', 'here', 'him', 'his', 'house', 'how', 'hundred', 'i', 'if', 'in', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'just', 'know', 'last', 'left', 'life', 'like', 'little', 'long', 'look', 'made', 'make', 'man', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'men', 'might', 'miles', 'more', 'most', 'mr', 'much', 'must', 'my', 'never', 'new', 'next', 'no', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'of', 'off', 'old', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'or', 'other', 'our', 'out', 'over', 'own', 'people', 'pilot', 'place', 'put', 'right', 'said', 'same', 'saw', 'say', 'says', 'see', 'seen', 'she', 'should', 'since', 'so', 'some', 'state', 'still', 'such', 'take', 'tell', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them', 'then', 'there', 'these', 'they', 'thing', 'think', 'this', 'those', 'thousand', 'three', 'through', 'time', 'times', 'to', 'told', 'too', 'took', 'two', 'under', 'up', 'upon', 'us', 'use', 'used', 'very', 'want', 'was', 'way', 'we', 'well', 'went', 'were', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'which', 'while', 'who', 'will', 'with', 'without', 'work', 'world', 'would', 'year', 'years', 'yes', 'yet', 'you', 'young', 'your']
```

What I want to do is for every word in list1, if the word equals a word from list2 delete that word from list1.

This is how I tried to tackle it:

```
for w in text1:
    for j in text2:
        if text[w] == text2[j]:
        text.remove[w]
    print(text)
```

**error message**

> text[w] == text2[j] must be an integer or a slice, not str

The objective is to try and remove the common words from the first list but comparing list2 with it. This could be the wrong way.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't remove items from a list that you're iterating over.  It'll appear/act as if items are "skipped".  Consider something like: `list1_without_2 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]`.

Comment: Thanks, that what I needed, knew I needed to use something else

Comment: indeed `set()` is made for this, use set to take this comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
lst1 = [x for x in lst1 if x not in lst2]
```

Take items from `lst1` that are not in `lst2` and that makes it simple and concise.

**Evaluating your code**

It's not advised to remove items from list while iterating over, as it would behave differently from what's expected.

Also, Python `for` is like a foreach loop, so when you do `for w in text1:`, you are taking items out of `text1`. In this context, `text1[w]` throws a `TypeError` as list indices must be integers or slices not str. Basically, you need just `w` there.

Comment: Thanks, won't let me choose your answer fro another 8 minutes. But I will

Comment: Also, this would be faster if `lst2` were a set. You could convert `lst1` to a set and use `set.difference` if there's no need to preserve order, but of course then there's the conversion time to consider.

Comment: @gilbo184,  when you have large dataset then set() are really faster .

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `set()` that is what it is made for..

## Your list1

```
>>> lst1 =  ['mississippi', 'well', 'worth', 'reading', 'not', 'commonplace', 'river', 'contrary', 'ways', 'remarkable', 'considering', 'missouri', 'main', 'branch', 'longest', 'river', 'world--four', 'miles', 'seems', 'safe', 'say', 'also', 'crookedest', 'river', 'since', 'in', 'one', 'part', 'journey', 'uses', 'one', 'three', 'miles', 'cover', 'same', 'ground', 'crow', 'fly', 'in', 'six', 'seventy-five', 'it', 'discharges', 'three', 'water', 'st', 'lawrence', 'twenty-five', 'as', 'as', 'rhine', 'three', 'thirty-eight', 'times', 'as', 'much', 'as', 'the', 'thames', 'other', 'river', 'so', 'vast', 'drainage-basin:', 'it', 'draws', 'its', 'water', 'supply', 'twenty-eight', 'states', 'territories', 'delaware', 'the', 'atlantic', 'seaboard', 'the', 'country', 'idaho', 'on', 'the', 'pacific', 'slope--a', 'spread', 'forty-five', 'degrees', 'longitude', 'the', 'mississippi', 'receives', 'carries', 'the', 'gulf', 'water', 'from', 'fifty-four', 'subordinate', 'rivers', 'are', 'navigable', 'steamboats', 'from', 'hundreds', 'that', 'are', 'navigable', 'flats', 'and', 'keels', 'the', 'area', 'its', 'drainage-basin', 'is', 'as', 'as', 'the', 'combined', 'areas', 'england', 'wales', 'scotland', 'ireland', 'france', 'spain', 'portugal', 'germany', 'austria', 'italy', 'and', 'turkey', 'and', 'almost', 'all', 'this', 'wide', 'region', 'is', 'fertile', 'the', 'mississippi', 'valley', 'proper', 'is', 'exceptionally', 'so']
```

## Your list2

```
>>> lst2 = ['a', 'about', 'after', 'again', 'against', 'ago', 'all', 'along', 'also', 'always', 'an', 'and', 'another', 'any', 'are', 'around', 'as', 'at', 'away', 'back', 'be', 'because', 'been', 'before', 'began', 'being', 'between', 'both', 'but', 'by', 'came', 'can', 'come', 'could', 'course', 'day', 'days', 'did', 'do', 'down', 'each', 'end', 'even', 'ever', 'every', 'first', 'for', 'four', 'from', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'going', 'good', 'got', 'great', 'had', 'half', 'has', 'have', 'he', 'head', 'her', 'here', 'him', 'his', 'house', 'how', 'hundred', 'i', 'if', 'in', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'just', 'know', 'last', 'left', 'life', 'like', 'little', 'long', 'look', 'made', 'make', 'man', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'men', 'might', 'miles', 'more', 'most', 'mr', 'much', 'must', 'my', 'never', 'new', 'next', 'no', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'of', 'off', 'old', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'or', 'other', 'our', 'out', 'over', 'own', 'people', 'pilot', 'place', 'put', 'right', 'said', 'same', 'saw', 'say', 'says', 'see', 'seen', 'she', 'should', 'since', 'so', 'some', 'state', 'still', 'such', 'take', 'tell', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them', 'then', 'there', 'these', 'they', 'thing', 'think', 'this', 'those', 'thousand', 'three', 'through', 'time', 'times', 'to', 'told', 'too', 'took', 'two', 'under', 'up', 'upon', 'us', 'use', 'used', 'very', 'want', 'was', 'way', 'we', 'well', 'went', 'were', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'which', 'while', 'who', 'will', 'with', 'without', 'work', 'world', 'would', 'year', 'years', 'yes', 'yet', 'you', 'young', 'your']
```

## List comparison:

```
>>> newlst = set(lst1) - set(lst2)
>>> newlst
{'uses', 'territories', 'area', 'longitude', 'twenty-eight', 'flats', 'crookedest', 'longest', 'country', 'cover', 'degrees', 'crow', 'six', 'ireland', 'missouri', 'combined', 'fertile', 'st', 'branch', 'commonplace', 'receives', 'draws', 'navigable', 'twenty-five', 'journey', 'pacific', 'carries', 'thirty-eight', 'keels', 'rhine', 'delaware', 'italy', 'thames', 'areas', 'exceptionally', 'england', 'spain', 'valley', 'seaboard', 'drainage-basin', 'seventy-five', 'water', 'almost', 'ways', 'atlantic', 'discharges', 'considering', 'slope--a', 'hundreds', 'part', 'supply', 'lawrence', 'france', 'region', 'safe', 'remarkable', 'vast', 'austria', 'forty-five', 'portugal', 'spread', 'states', 'worth', 'mississippi', 'idaho', 'fly', 'steamboats', 'seems', 'wide', 'scotland', 'germany', 'contrary', 'river', 'ground', 'wales', 'drainage-basin:', 'proper', 'reading', 'rivers', 'fifty-four', 'subordinate', 'turkey', 'world--four', 'gulf', 'main'}
```

**OR Simply use:**

```
>>> set(lst1).difference(lst2)
```

**Note :** Just be cautious as sets will not preserve order if that is important

Answer (score 0):

Or `filterflase`:

```
print(list(filterfalse(list2.__contains__,list1)))
```

**Demo:**

```
list1=['a','b']
list2=['a']
from itertools import filterfalse
print(list(filterfalse(list2.__contains__,list1)))
```

Output:

```
['b']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the items in the lists are unique and if you also don't care about the order, then you can use `set`

```
set(list1) - set(list2)
```

This would returns the elements from `list1` that are not in `list2`

Comment: @ kmario set() is the correct for this type of usage , i also provided the answer using sed() already :-)

Answer (score 0):

All other methods seem to have been touched on, another one that would work here would be to use the traditional `filter` *not `filterfalse`*. You could filter `list1` for all the elements that are `not in list2`, what will happen is all `words` that appear in `list2` will not be included in the filtered result

```
list3 = list(filter(lambda x: x not in list2, list1))
```